# Wait for a function to return value without impacting framerate

Tags: unity, multithreading, coroutines

I'm looking to do some possibly heavy calculation in my game. An agent in my game needs to evaluate up to 1000 objects while performing heavy calculations to select his next job.

I want to either offload this to a separate thread (and wait for it to finish) without blocking and causing stuttering on the main Unity thread, or I'd like to use coroutines to spread the heavy calculations over multiple frames.

```
public static Job RequestJob()
{
    Job suitableJob = JobManager.FindSuitableJob(Jobs);
    if (suitableJob != null)
    {
        DequeueJob(suitableJob as PlantCutJob);
        return suitableJob;
    }

    return null;
}
```

I'd like the `JobManager.FindSuitableJob` method to be spread during several frames or multithreaded. This is the method:

```
public static FindSuitableJob (List<Job> jobs)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < jobs.Count; i++)
    {
        if (jobs[i].CheckRequirements())
        {

            return jobs[i];
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

I have tried making a couroutine, which seems like exactly what I need, but I need to call it outside of a `MonoBehavior` (from just a regular class) which I'm not sure is possible without some heavy workarounds. I have no experience with coroutines or multithreading in Unity and C# so any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Since you can spawn a GameObject on demand from non-GameObject code, you can always create an object to run your coroutines on your behalf, even if you're not in a MonoBehavíour.

Comment: You may be interested in [How to not freeze the main thread in Unity](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/113096/39518).

Comment: I'm more interested (if using Coroutines) how to get the return value of those coroutines back to my non-monobehavior class. Can coroutines simply "return" a value, or do I need to do some special callbacks? I haven't been able to find a case like this anywhere online

Comment: If you want to ask "How can I get an output value from a thread or coroutine" then that's a general programming problem that [you can find answered on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=return+from+coroutine+%5Bc%23%5D).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my game, I needed to have a character look for available jobs to do, but I didn't want it to evaluate too many jobs in one frame.

My solution was to start a `RequestJob` coroutine which takes an `Action<Job>` as a parameter, and when it's found a job it calls this callback and passes in the job it found. The script from which you call the coroutine subscribes to this callback and does something after the job is received.

Of course, inside the coroutine, I can `yield return null` if too many jobs have been evaluated in one frame.